# Jump Links not working on my Website

Tags: jquery, html, vertical-scrolling, page-jump

For my website, I have a one page system as the index to showcase several different parts of my portfolio.  In my designs section I have categories that visitors can click on which will take them to another page.  On that page I have a "back" button when they click, it should take them back to the index and scroll down to the designs area so that they don't have to scroll down again to look at another section.

Right now I have `<a id="designs"></a>` just above the div that I have my design category in.

On the category page that has the "back" button, the link is my URL with `index.html#designs`

Maybe I am doing this wrong but when I reload the page, it goes to the position I want for like a milisecond, and then it scrolls to the top.

Is there any way to make it so that it will not scroll to the top of the page?  I don't want it to be a challenge for people to view my portfolio.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your html like,

```
<!-- add href like #designs -->
<a href="#designs">Design</a>

<!-- div design having id designs which you want to show on top -->
<div id="designs">Design div</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RH7Ux/)

Comment: This works when I am just jumping to something on the same page, but I am trying to have a link from another page go back to my index and straight to my design area.  I tried doing what you said and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Test it with different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**:

```
$('#designs').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

This selector only target the `#designs` anchor. You can give all of your expected anchors a common class such as `class="anchors"` then you can do:

```
$('.anchors').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is that I am linking it from another page, the jump to the top is happening on the loading of the page, when I put this in it made no change.